# Can a NEMA 24 motor be driven using a NEMA 34 stepper driver?

Tags: stepper-motor

I got a system that's being powered by a 12S LiPo battery which fluctuates with its voltage from **44.4V-50.4V** (3.7V/cell, 4.2V/cell). Now **the problem is that most Nema 24 drivers I found at [Stepperonline](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/) have a MAX input voltage of 50V** (which is a bit lower than needed). [This is the NEMA 24 I'll be using](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/dual-shaft-nema-24-stepper-motor-4-2a-4nm-566-oz-in-60x60x100mm-4-wires-24hs39-4204d)(rated current draw: 4.2A). So the question is, **can I use a slightly bigger driver (intended for NEMA 34) to drive my NEMA 24?** I know 50.4V is not far away from 50V but I wanted to be on the safe side.

[This is the stepper driver that is **maxed at 50V**](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/digital-stepper-driver-1-8-5-6a-20-50vdc-for-nema-23-24-34-stepper-motor-dm556t) (intended for NEMA 24), and [this is the one that can take **between 36-110VDC**](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/digital-stepper-driver-2-4-7-2a-18-80vac-or-36-110vdc-for-nema-34-motor-dm860t) (intended for NEMA 34).